# Extending classes php

Tags: php, class, oop

How can I get the value of class A extends Class B ?

```
class A{
    private $a;

    public function setA($a){ $this->a = $a; }
    public function getA (){ return $this->a; }
}
class B extends A{

}

$a = new A();
$a->setA("Hello");

$b = new B(); 
echo($b->getA());    //empty
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: uh, `class B extends A { ...}`? as written, you have no inheritance anywhere. A and B are completely independent.

Comment: @jbafford, I want to call getA function on class B

Comment: @MarcB , sorry my bad ... I already edited ..

Comment: `$x = new B(); $x->setA('HELLO WORLD'); var_dump($x->getA());` Where's the problem?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php ?

Comment: If you are wanting to create an instance of `B` based on an already-created (and populated) instance of `A`, then you probably want to [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) it.

Comment: @MarkBaker the problem is when I call $b->getA() is empty

Comment: Well unless you've set a value for in the $a property, it will be empty.... look at the code that I posted in my comment; I set a value before calling `getA()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it seems that you want to create an instance of class `B` that maintains the already-populated values of an existing instance of class `A` (while not just being a reference to it), you want to use PHP's [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) feature.

```
class A{
    private $a;

    public function setA($a){ $this->a = $a; }
    public function getA (){ return $this->a; }
}


class B extends A{
    //
}


$a = new A();
$a->setA("Hello");

$b = clone $a;

echo $b->getA();  // output is "Hello"
```

Comment: `class B` appears to be irrelevant here. If OP actually does need a `B` that has its `$a` set, this won't do it. In this example `$b` is still an `A`. But it's kind of hard to tell from the question if `B` really is needed at all or if it was just introduced because the OP did not know about clone.

Comment: @Don'tPanic True, it is unclear what exactly the OP is going for here.  My solution simply gives the requested result.  Whether or not it does so the way the OP intended is hard to say.